# Problem about proving not cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that if p is a prime number and G is a finite group containing at least p elements of order p, then G is not cyclic.

I thought I start with contradiction, suppose that G is cyclic and G=$<g>$, then $|G|=kp$, then I have not idea. could somebody give me some hit. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** if $G = \langle g \rangle$ with order $k\cdot p$, then how many elements will have order $p$?  That is, which elements of $G$ will have some order dividing $p$, and of those, which will be of exactly order $p$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** In a cyclic group of order $n$, if $1\le d|n$ then there are exactly $\phi(d)$ elements of order $d$, where $\phi$ is the Euler's phi function.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

A finite cyclic group of order $\;n\;$ has, for each divisor $\;d\;$ of $\;n\;$ , a **unique** subgroup of order $\;d\;$ .

But how many elements of order $\;p\;$ does a cyclic group of order $\;p\;$ have? And yet you have $\;p\;$ element of order $\;p\;$ , so....

Comment: if G is a cyclic group, it has order of $kp$,then there can only be one group of order p, but there are p groups of order p which is a contradiction, is that right?

Comment: No...If $\;G\;$ has *at least* $\;p\;$ elements of order $\;p\;$ then it does **not** contain a **unique** subgroup of order $\;p\;$ , since a cyclic subgroup of order $\;p\;$  has...how many elements of order $\;p\;$ ?

Comment: a cyclic subgroup of order p can have only one element of order p

Comment: @user121819, you should try a little harder before you rush up to answer. Why don't you try some simple examples, say with $\;p=3,5,7\;$ and check how many elementso of order $\;3,3\;or\; 7\;$ each cyclic has?

Comment: there should be two elements of order $p$

Comment: @user121819, please do observe **closely** the cyclic group of order $\;5\;$, say $\;\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z=:\Bbb Z_5\;$ or any other isomorphic representation of it. How many elements of order $\;5\;$ does this group have?!

Comment: it should be p-1 elements of order p.Is this correct.

Comment: Ah, not that's correct @user121819 . Now you understand my hint?